# automatically adjust IPython widgets layout

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm creating an interactive `jupyter notebook` with [`ipython widgets`](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets) and want the user to select from a certain number of checkboxes. I'm using the code below to visualize the [`HBox`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.html.widgets.widget_box.html) that contains the checkboxes.

```
num_checks = 10

cb_cont = widgets.HBox(background_color='red',height='100px',width='100%')

checkboxes = []
for f in range(num_checks):
    checkboxes.append(\
        widgets.Checkbox(description = 'Checkbox [%d]'%(f), \
                         value=False, width=50))

cb_cont.children=[i for i in checkboxes]
display(cb_cont)
```

Here is a screenshot of the output from the above code:

[image]

As you can see, the content of the box overflows and goes beyond the width of the container.

I can change the behavior by setting the `overflow_x` property to be one of the following: `['visible', 'hidden', 'scroll', 'auto', 'initial', 'inherit', '']`.

For instance, `cb_cont.overflow_x = 'scroll'` results in the following output window:

[image]

in which the content doesn't overflow but becomes invisible and can be scrolled.

**How can I set the property of the box to visualize the content that does not fit on a newline?**

Obviously I could use multiple `HBox` objects each one containing the maximum number of checkboxes that fit in a window size, however this is not the wanted solution for a set of reasons:

1. Depending on the screen resolution that number could change.
2. The number of checkboxes to pick from depends on a previous computation ans is not known it in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue with the widgets and after toying around with the various Box properties, here is what I came up with:

You need to set the following properties:

- `display`: 'inline-flex'
- `flex_flow`: 'row wrap'

This worked for me with any number of checkboxes (I tried up to 100). On the other hand, setting the height property was not very useful. You need the height to adapt depending on the number of checkboxes or screen resolution.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import *
from IPython.display import display

num_checks = 50

cb_cont = HBox(layout=Layout(width='100%',display='inline-flex',flex_flow='row wrap'))
#cb_cont.overflow_x = 'scroll'

checkboxes = []
for f in range(num_checks):
    checkboxes.append(\
        widgets.Checkbox(description = 'Checkbox [%d]'%(f), \
                     value=False, width=50))

cb_cont.children=[i for i in checkboxes]
display(cb_cont)
```

Comment: I've been playing around with the flex_flow and flex_wrap properties for a while and couldn't make the box wrap the items when the items were Dropdown elements. It only worked with other elements like buttons and such.
Your answer worked and was spot on! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use percentage for the width (and height):

```
cb_cont = widgets.HBox(background_color='red',height='100px',width='100%')
```

and set `cb_cont.overflow_x = 'auto'`